# эффективное кэширование php javascript ajax

Tags: кэширование

Как эффективно кэшировать через скрипты php когда на сайте отключен JS, как кэшировать когда имеется js и когда используется ajax запрос.

Comment: кешировать что?

Answer (score 0):

Для начала, пара строк теории.
Скрипты php работают на сервере, js - в браузере локального компьютера. (Есть, конечно, node.js и прочее, но, судя по вопросу, мы говорим о наиболее распространенных сайтах на основе php.)

php формирует страницу в коде html+js для передачи локальному браузеру.

js выполняется в локальном браузере. js может инициировать ajax-запрос к серверу (выполнение куска кода php на сервере) для получения некоторых данных от сервера (например, выборки из базы данных товаров).

Кэширование - процесс запоминания на сервере (в памяти, в файле) полученного html+js кода страницы и выдачи его по запросу на сервер.

Теперь к вопросу. Кэширование производится на стороне сервера либо серверными пакета типа Varnish, либо php-плагинами. Страница запоминается в коде html+php перед выдачей в браузер посетителя. При следующем обращении, если страница не изменилась, не будет вызываться php код, а будет быстро выдан "слепок" страницы.

Часть вопроса "когда на сайте отключен JS" содержит неточность. На сайте нельзя отключить js, потому что его там нет. js можно отключить только в браузере. Теоретически. Потому что после этого 90% современных сайтов перестанут работать.

Тем не менее, для процесса кэширования это не имеет значения. В любом случае сервер запоминает html+js.

Кэшировать ajax-запрос невозможно в принципе, т.е. по определению. Весь смысл ajax запроса из браузера на домашнем компьютере к серверу в условном Чикаго состоит в том, чтобы получить новые данные и отобразить их на странице. Однако объем этих данных обычно маленький.

Возможен вариант, когда 100% закэшированная страница дает запрос ajax при нажатии на кнопку и локально изменяет малую часть своего содержимого на компьютере посетителя. К кэшу это не имеет никакого отношения.

Кэш нужен для быстрой выдачи *начального* содержимого страницы.

Подводя итоги.

1. Нет разницы, как кэшировать при выключенном или включенном js в *браузере* пользователя. На сервере js не выполняется, но в любом случае добавляется посредством php в код страницы.
2. Невозможно кэшировать ajax-запрос.

Comment: Хорошо теперь ближе к делу)